# .py to .exe with icon , images and chromedriver

Tags: python, tkinter, exe

I have a GUI program which has icons and some images and chromedriver.
Now I want to convert the .py file to .exe with having icon, images and the chromedriver inside the exe. How can I achieve this?

I have tried pyinstaller and that works but I have to keep the icons and chromedriver inside the folder where the exe is and then only it would work but I want it to be inside the exe where i can just distribute the exe to my friend without the chromedriver.

Comment: did you try with -- onefile options?

Comment: Yes it is onefile option but then I need the chrome driver inside the .exe "folder" to actually use it what i want is the chromedrive to be inside the exe file itself

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
pyinstaller --onefile --windowed --icon=app.ico test.py
```

Also, add chrome driver in `test.spec` file,

```
binaries=[('path\chromedriver.exe', '.')]
```

Update the spec file, like `pyinstaller test.spec`.

You can also update the app icon via the spec file.`icon='app.ico'`

Comment: Yes but I have no idea how to work with the spec or what spec is. Is there any link that I can refer to for beginners ?

Comment: After you run the first command. that will automatically create a test.spec file in the same file location with values in it. you only need to update the `binaries` with your respective chrome driver path. and update `pyinstaller test.spec`. it will work.

Comment: I think the chromedriver part is good but the problem is the Icon. Now I got the icon to work but when I move it to another computer it fails because the icon is not present in the pc. How to get around this?

Comment: running the command with `--icon=path/app.ico` as an option will create the icon and the executable will be same in any systems with the same icon.
are you sure that icon works perfectly in your local system?
does it have the right format?

Comment: Okay but the icon does not show it on the exe launcher it is still the Python logo, when I open the app then on the top left the icon shows. How can I make it show on the exe launcher?

Comment: checkout the doc and do like that, I have done the same and worked.